# str.replace gives s[i-1] out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

def super_reduced_string(s):   
    i=len(s)-1  
    while(i>0):  
        if(s[i]==s[i-1]):
            s=s.replace(s[i],'')
            s=s.replace(s[i-1],'')
            i=len(s)-1
        else:
            i-=1
    return (s)
```

For example, if I take a string `"aaabccddd"` so the value of `i` is 8 at the start. My `if` statement is true so the string becomes `'aaabccdd'`.

After then I want to remove `s[i-1]` (`s[7]`) then your string should become `"aaabccd"`

Why does it raise an `IndexError` exception, saying that `s[i-1]` out of range?

Comment: `s.replace(s[i],'')` doesn't mean "replace the `i`th character". If the `i`th character is `'d'`, it means "replace all `'d'`s".

Comment: Hint : What you want to do is not `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

You are removing **multiple characters**. `str.replace()` finds **all** occurrences of the given string and replaces them. `s[8]` is `'d'`, so you removed **all** `'d'` characters from your string:

```
>>> s = 'aaabccddd'
>>> i = len(s) - 1
>>> i
8
>>> s.replace(s[i], '')
'aaabcc'
```

Now `s` is only 6 characters long, so `s[i-1]` is `s[7]` is out of range.

If you wanted to remove just **one** character from your string, don't use `str.replace()`; you'd have to use slicing:

```
s = s[:i - 1] + s[i + 1:]  # remove the doubled character found
```

Slicing always succeeds, it'll never throw an `IndexError`, but can result in an empty string.

Working code (with some PEP-8 whitespace thrown in):

```
def super_reduced_string(s):   
    i = len(s) - 1 
    while i:  
        if s[i] == s[i-1]:
            s = s[:i - 1] + s[i + 1:]
            i = len(s) - 1
        else:
            i -= 1
    return s
```

This produces:

```
>>> super_reduced_string('aaabccddd')
'abd'
```